# Flutter app run on real device but not from apk

Tags: android, flutter

I've connected my real device on computer, when I run `flutter run --release --verbose` everything works well but when I run `flutter build apk` and install apk, the app launch but seems to not download a file

```
await Dio().download(fileurl, savePath);
```

or can't read it (I don't know because I've no log from apk and can't check the file download with not rooted real device using getApplicationDocumentsDirectory)

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/file.gpx');
  }

  _readGPX() async {
    print("_readGPX");
    final myTransformer = Xml2Json();
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      final goodXmlString = await file.readAsString();

      myTransformer.parse(goodXmlString);
      var jsondata = myTransformer.toParkerWithAttrs();

      setState(() {
        _trkpt = jsonDecode(jsondata)['gpx']['trk']['trkseg']['trkpt'];
        if (_trkpt != null) {
          setState(() {
            _gpxLoaded = true;
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add internet permission in androidmanifest file. android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hardik Mehta

In manifest add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`